# Unique auto increment reference number that resets at the 1st of each month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with various fields involving jobs done on ships including a field named **created**  which uses DATE format. The result i want to achieve is to have a unique reference number for each job. The format i want to use for this reference number is:

***example :***  Lets say the date of the job is 23/11/2013 like today. Then the number would be 1311/1 the next job 1311/2 and goes on. If the month changes and the date of the next job is for example 15/12/2013 the refence number i would like to have if its the first job of the month is 1312/1.

So the two first digits of my reference number would show the year,the next two the month and the number after the slash i would like it to be an auto_increment number that will reset each month.My code so far is :

```
    $job_num = 1;
foreach($random as $rand) {
    $vak = $rand->created;
    $gas = $rand->id;
    $vak1 = substr($vak, 2, 2);
    $vak2 = substr($vak, 5, -3);
    $vak3 = substr($vak, 8, 10);

    if(date(j) > 1) {
        echo $vak1.$vak2.'/'.$job_num.'<br>';
        $job_num++;
    } else {
        $job_num = 1; 
        echo $vak1.$vak2.'/'.$job_num.'<br>';
        $job_num++;
      }

}
```

So as u can see i want to achieve all this inside a **foreach** statement. And although the above code kinda works,the porblem i have is that at the 1st of any month in other words when `date(j) = 1`  if i insert more than one job in my database the `$job_num` variable resets as many times as the jobs i have inserted resulting in identical refence numbers.

I am really new in programming and php so if anyone could help me solve this, i would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: 1. Insert a row without a reference number 2. Then calculate the reference number

Comment: Use a Window Function or LAG function at query time

Comment: @Randy: won't there be issues in a high concurrency environment?

Comment: @zerkms: Thank you for your reply but can you explain what you mean a little better?

Comment: @Stefanos Vakirtzis: I'm not sure I can provide even more details. You just split the whole process into 2 steps: 1. you `insert` a row **without** a reference number. 2. you `update` a row with a reference number which you can calculate now

Comment: @zerkms:Nevermind my stupidity i finally understood what you suggested in the 1st place thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the MyISAM engine, you can get this behavior without procedural code.

```
create table demo (
  yr_mo integer not null,
  id integer auto_increment,
  other_columns char(1) default 'x',
  primary key (yr_mo, id)
) engine=MyISAM;

insert into demo (yr_mo) values (1311);
insert into demo (yr_mo) values (1311);
insert into demo (yr_mo) values (1311);
insert into demo (yr_mo) values (1311);
insert into demo (yr_mo) values (1312);
```

The last INSERT statement starts a new month.

Now if you look at the autoincrement values the MyISAM engine assigned . . .

```
select * from demo;

YR_MO  ID   OTHER_COLUMNS
--
1311   1    x
1311   2    x
1311   3    x
1311   4    x
1312   1    x
```

This is [MyISAM's documented behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html); look for "MyISAM Notes".

If you want the form yymm/n for presentation, use something like this.

```
select concat(yr_mo, '/', id) as cat_key
from demo;
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but due to my lack of knowledge of SQL and limited knowledge of php,(as i mentioned it's only been a week i am learning), i couldnt reply faster. After some reading on wht exactly u were telling me to do i think your solution works for me. (although i still cant understand how in ur table the id changes each time yr_mo does ).  Thanks a lot,  really appreciated.

Comment: The ID changes, because that's what MySQL's MyISAM engine is programmed to do. (Read the linked document.) If you're kind of new to this, you should read the linked articles in Bill Karwin's answer before you make up your mind.

Comment: My bad i didnt look at your link. I grasped the basic idea of MyISAM and why the id is changing. Now going to read why i shouldn't use MyISAM as you suggested. Really sorry for wasting your time explaining me the whole thing:)

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis, the reason is that MyISAM isn't stable, and is gradually being phased out. MyISAM doesn't support any of the characteristics of an [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database, and it's susceptible to frequent data corruption.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Thank you Bill for your all your useful info. You convinced me not to use MyISAM and use innoDB instead but now i have to go and learn locking tables (i ve been learning php for like 1 and a half week) which i have absolutely no idea in order to solve my problem:)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the auto-increment mechanism if you use InnoDB, which is MySQL's default storage engine.

You can do it with the MyISAM storage engine, but you [really shouldn't use MyISAM, for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148).

So you'll have to assign the repeating numbers yourself. This means you have to lock the table while you check what is the current maximum number for the given month, then insert a new row with the next higher number.

If that seems like it would impair concurrent access to the table, you're right. Keep in mind that MyISAM does a table-lock during insert/update/delete of any row.

Comment: It can be done lock-free. Just have another table `ref_id_sequence` with `(id int PK, ref_id varchar NULLABLE)` columns and insert a row `(id) values (null)`, then `update` the row with a reference number and then it's possible to insert the row into another table with unique reference id

Comment: @zerkms, I don't understand how you mean that to work, without causing a race condition.

Comment: after you inserted a row without `ref_id` specified - you can easily perform `COUNT()` to see how many rows are there in the current month before currently inserted row. That's it

Comment: @zerkms, so what happens if two sessions are doing the same count in separate transactions, they both produce the same total, and then they both try to update with the same ref_id. That's what I mean by a race condition in this case. The only way to resolve this is with locking the table (or at least the subset of rows for the current month) until the update is complete.

Comment: I intentionally put the name for it - `ref_id_sequence`. As *any other* sequence it should be non-transactional.

Comment: Or, if one doesn't want it to be non-transactional - with unique index on `ref_id` it's possible to implement lock-free strategy as well: just insert a row in a loop until it's get inserted without unique key constraint violation.

Comment: I don't see the point. There are 10k rows already. Then after you insert a row and perform `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ref_id_sequence WHERE date is the same month AND ref_id IS NOT NULL` and get 10k. Then you perform `10k + 1` and update your current row. So: 1. INSERT with `ref_id = NULL` 2. while(unique constraint violation) { SELECT COUNT + UPDATE `ref_id = 'YYMM' || cnt+1` }

Comment: @zerkms, aha, that's different from what you described before, which was a loop of inserts.

Comment: it was probably worse expressed, but the same thoughts :-) PS: yep, I just confused you and myself, sorry